# DataTable not recognize as a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, datatables

Why does the `DataTable()` does not recognize as a function? 
Here is my code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#account_table').DataTable({
                    });
                }); 
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table style="width:100%;" role="grid" id="account_table" class="table table-bordered dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0">
                <thead align="center" >
                    <tr role="row" align="center" >
                        <th style="width: 200px;" class="sorting_asc">Balance</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${AccountsList}" var="list">
                        <tr><td>${list.accounts}</td></tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#account_table').removeClass('display').addClass('table table-bordered');
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

though I already link the js file for DataTable still it does not work

Comment: Try removing either one of the dataTables-js-files - preferably the bootstrap one, and see if it works then.

Comment: try to load those scripts at the end of the file before closing the </body>

Comment: Why are you targeting such an old version of jQuery?

Comment: If I had to guess I would assume you need to update to at least jQuery 2, here you can see your code is correct otherwise: https://jsfiddle.net/vobxq5yc/

Comment: @JasonSperske DataTables 1.10 only requires jQuery 1.7 or later.